# c# How to deserialise from an XML file and display the properties in a windows form?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an XML file and and a class representing the XML structure. I have deserialized the XML file into the class.  I want to display all the properties into the form.  Can anyone suggest if it is possible and how to deserialize the XML into datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, de-serialization involves have a valid class structure and or object to de-serialize the thing into, whether that is Xml deserialization, or Binary, or SOAP...etc etc.  You have the class, so the de-serialize step will be simple enough, just create the serializer and call `deserialize(xml)`.  As for the second part...well, you have to create a datagridview and bind to the object.

so, yes, totally possible.  without access to the object, the class definition, or the xml, this is all the information I can give you.

Some basic code structure.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass obj = ser.DeSerialize(xmlDoc);

MyDataGridView.DataSource = obj;
```